# Counting the number of inversions in a given array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, mergesort

I tried to solve this problem using merge sort but there is something wrong with my solution. I checked number of inversions while merging the array.
Can someone help me find the issue?

```
void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r)
{
    int n1=m-l+1;
    int n2=r-m;
    int left[(n1+1)];
    int right[(n2+1)];
    for(int i=0;i<n1;i++){
        left[i]=arr[l+i];
    }
    for(int j=0;j<n2;j++){
        right[j]=arr[m+j+1];
    }
    left[n1]=INT_MAX;
    right[n2]=INT_MAX;
    int i=0, j=0;
    //int inv=0;
    for(int k=l;k<=r;k++){
        if(left[i]<=right[j]){
            arr[k]=left[i];
            i++;
        }
        else{
            arr[k]=right[j];
            j++;
            inv+=(m-i);
        }
    }
    //return inv;
}

void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r) {
    int inv=0;
    if (l < r) {
        int m = l+(r-l)/2;
        mergeSort(arr, l, m);
        mergeSort(arr, m+1, r);
        merge(arr, l, m, r);
    }
    // return inv;
}
```

Comment: I recommend refining the code sample a bit, using better spacing, comments, and variable names.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing everything correctly, except that you have to add `n1 - i` to `inv` instad of `m - i`.

The reasoning behind that is the following. When you take a number from the "right" part, it is lower than any number in the "left" part that hasn't been taken yet, and thus such pairs form inversions. The number of untaken items from "left" part is `n1 - 1`[last number from actual array. INT_MAX is stored at index `n1`] - `i`[current untaken item] + `1`[because the indices are inclusive], which simplifies to `n1 - i`.

Please also note that the number of inversions can be as high as `O(n ^ 2)`, where `n` is the size of the array, so you might want to store the number of inversions in a `long long` variable.

The final version of the code:

```
int merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r)
{
    int n1=m-l+1;
    int n2=r-m;
    int left[(n1+1)];
    int right[(n2+1)];
    for(int i=0;i<n1;i++){
        left[i]=arr[l+i];
    }
    for(int j=0;j<n2;j++){
        right[j]=arr[m+j+1];
    }
    left[n1]=INT_MAX;
    right[n2]=INT_MAX;
    int i=0, j=0;
    int inv=0;
    for(int k=l;k<=r;k++){
        if(left[i]<=right[j]){
            arr[k]=left[i];
            i++;
        }
        else{
            arr[k]=right[j];
            j++;
            inv += n1 - i;
        }
    }
    return inv;
}

int mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r) {
    int inv=0;
    if (l < r) {
        int m = l+(r-l)/2;
        inv += mergeSort(arr, l, m);
        inv += mergeSort(arr, m+1, r);
        inv += merge(arr, l, m, r);
    }
    return inv;
}
```